# What causes this error This org does not have access to Lightning Pages of type RecordPage?

Tags: appexchange, package-install

Im trying to install Agile Accelerator on a gov cloud sandbox and get the followint errors.  Note that i have enabled my domain and have the org lightning enabled.

Problem:

1. (Product_Tag_Record_Page) Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)
   There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "This org does not have access to Lightning Pages of type RecordPage.".
2. (Team_Detail_Page) Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)
   There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "This org does not have access to Lightning Pages of type RecordPage.".
3. (Theme_Record_Page) Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)
   There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "This org does not have access to Lightning Pages of type RecordPage.".
4. (User_Record_Page2) Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)
   There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "This org does not have access to Lightning Pages of type RecordPage.".
5. (Work_Record_Page) Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)
   There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "This org does not have access to Lightning Pages of type RecordPage.".

Comment: what happens in this org when you click on Lightning App Builder and try to customize a page (or click edit page on a record's detail screen to do the same)?

Comment: When i try the edit page option - i get the message below:  URL No Longer Exists
You have attempted to reach a URL that no longer exists on salesforce.com. 

You may have reached this page after clicking on a direct link into the application. This direct link might be: 
• A bookmark to a particular page, such as a report or view 
• A link to a particular page in the Custom Links section of your Home Tab, or a Custom Link 
• A link to a particular page in your email templates ..... When i try to navigate to Lighning App builder - i dont see the option in setup.  Thank you for your help

Comment: Does your user have the Customize Application and View Setup and Configuration permissions? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_app_builder_create_app_page.htm

Comment: Yup - System admin out of the box profile. Have both of those permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd chime in here - I had this same issue. Submitted a case to Salesforce and they were able to fix it. Nothing you can do on your end - it's something they have to do. ONLY was an issue for me with an org that was on classic and transitioned to Lightning.